# How to use unique constraint such that every key:value pair is the same in a json type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I set a unique constraint for "json" column in postgresql? Unique means this for me: A json object is unique if every key matches and every value of the json object matches.

Answer (score 17):

This is not possible with your somewhat outdated version 9.4

Postgres 9.5 introduced a different JSON type, named `jsonb` which does support an equality operator. So if you really, really need this, you will have to upgrade to a more up-to-date version (e.g. 10 or 11)

The `json` data type preserves the ordering of the input value and thus makes comparison really complicated (at least not efficient).

The `jsonb` type normalizes the key/values and stores the data in binary 
format which enables efficient equality checking.

e.g.

```
'{"foo": 42, "bar": "value"}'::jsonb = '{"bar": "value", "foo": 42}'::jsonb
```

returns `true`. The same expression with a cast to `json` results in an error.

So the following DDL works:

```
create table data 
(
  id        serial primary key,
  payload   jsonb,
  unique (payload)
);
```

---

However, there is a limit on how large an index entry is allowed to be (something around 2000 byte). So it might happen that inserting data into such a table fails not because of the violation of the  unique constraint, but because the JSON value is too big.

---

One option with Postgres 9.4 would be to create a unique index on the MD5 hash of the JSON value.

```
create unique index on data ( md5(payload::text) );
```

But that will **only** work if you always specify the keys inside the JSON in exactly the same order. Because the md5 hash of `'{"foo": 42, "bar": "value"}'` is different than the one for `'{"bar": "value"}, "foo": 42'`

---

Some questions with solutions to index large text values:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144575
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69161
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69170
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217087/

Comment: Given the case I'll switch to jsonb: Is there an effective way to overcome the limitation of the index size? Can I use a hash for jsonb without the "right order" limitation?

Comment: `Can I use a hash for jsonb without the "right order" limitation?` By definition of the hashing function, no.