# Can in postgres /mysql сan I define unique index based on json field?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

If with postgres 14 /mysql 8 servers can I define unique index based on json field ?

With next migration :

```
Schema::create('quiz_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->json('name')->comment('This column is used for i18n support');
    $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(['name', 'active'], 'quiz_categories_name_active_index');
});
```

I got error :

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  data type json has no default operator class for access method "btree"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type. (Connection: pgsql, SQL: alter table "quiz_categories" add constraint "quiz_categories_name_active_index" unique ("name", "active"))
```

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389075/how-to-create-index-on-json-column-in-mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148719/how-to-use-unique-constraint-for-json-type-in-postgresql

Comment: Thank you, interesting links, but which syntax would be in migration file ?

Comment: Use `->storedAs()` to create a generated column. It is mentioned in the Laravel docs, but with no example. See example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290032/20860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a unique index in PostgreSQL on a JSON field, but there are some extra steps involved. PostgreSQL doesn't provide a default operator class for "btree" access method on the JSON data type.
But jsonb provides a default operator class for the "btree" access function, so you can use it instead of json to create a unique index on a JSON field.
This is how to change your migration to make use of jsonb.

```
Schema::create('quiz_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->jsonb('name')->comment('This column is used for i18n support');
    $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(['name', 'active'], 'quiz_categories_name_active_index');
});
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks !, looks like it works ! Would jsonb work for mysql 8  ?

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't have a jsonb data type like PostgreSQL.